# How to understanding the logic behind this programming task? (Beginner)

Tags: math, logic, percentage

The task states:
Saver A has £25,000 which they purchase a new car with, the car loses 20% of its value each year.  Saver B has £25,000 which they invest in the property market and make a rental yield of 8% each year.
Using a while loop, calculate and output which year does Saver B have 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 times as much money of Saver A.

I am having an issue with what exactly this logic states rather than programming it.

If Saver A has 25k, which they buy a car with, and then it loses 20% per year, does it mean that it loses 20% of the original value (so 5k per year every year) or that it loses 20% of the value that it becomes over the years, so first it would lose 5k so the car would be worth 20k, so then it would be 20% of the 20k that is the loss of value that year.

It's sort of the same case for Saver B. I don't see why he would get more each year from a rental property than he got before, houses just don't increase in value that drastically. It seems to me like it would be 8% of the original 25k every year, but what does the question actually say for me to do?

I am planning to do a for loop for 2,3,4,5,6 etc. and then inside a while loop. Inside the while loop I actually need to money of A and B so... this is the calculations I need to find out how to do.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is generally how it works. Take the current value and add or deduct the percentage value.
Otherwise the car would reach negative value after only 5 years.
Otherwise the house would increase its value linearily, when infation and market do not. The house would almost stagnate after decades.

So in each loop, calculate the loss/earnings based on current value and substract/add it.

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the task as you have provided it is perhaps not as clear as it could be ... but that is very common when requirements for a programming job are specified!

The calculation of a depreciating value of the car should definitely be 20% of the previous year's value, not 20% of the original value.

The calculation of rental income is different. The question does not require you to factor in any change in the value of the investment property, just the income from rent. So that investor simply receives a fixed amount (8% of £25,000) each year. At least that's the way I read the question.

If I were you, I'd ask the person who set the task to clarify it. That's what I'd do in real life too -- if the requirements are ambiguous, don't just assume what you think they mean, ask the client to clarify.

With regard to the "while loop", just notice that the loop has to go year-by-year, but the output is *not* year-by-year: the code does not output a value each time through the loop. Within the loop you will need to accumulate the value of each Savers' asset (The task says to compare the "money" each saver has, but that is also less than clear -- Saver A has no money, just a depreciating asset; Saver B receives rental money each year and that has to be added to the fixed value of the asset. So that might also need clarification.) Anyway, once you accumulate the value for each Saver within the current year, then the code within the loop needs to decide whether or not to output a message like "Saver B's value exceeded 2 times Saver A's value in year ".